# iOS Push Notifications don't adds to Notification Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I realizing push notification handling on my iOS application on Xamarin.iOS platform but my problem actual for iOS native too.
I need to handle push notification when my application is in Background Mode for some reasons, so I turn on  **Background Mode** and **Push Notification** using in my project. Also I include the **content-available** key with a value of **1** into the payload’s aps dictionary. Also I include **alert**, **badge** and **sound** keys because I want to show this push notification for user and add it into Notification Center.

As a result after push notification receiving in Background Mode (when application is not active):
1) I handle push notification receiving using *DidReceiveRemoteNotification()* method.
2) The user see notification rolls down from the top of the screen as a banner.
3) I change application icon badge counter.
My problem is that **push notification don't adds to Notification Center** after all this actions.
As I understand after handling the push notification in *DidReceiveRemoteNotification()* method iOS mark this notification like *handled* and doesn't add them to Notification Center. As possible solution I can create Local Notification, schedule them and it'll added to Notification Center but the user will again see notification rolls down from the top of the screen as a banner and that's not good (it looks like user gets 2 notifications but only 1 shows in Notification Center).
What's the actual reason for this behaviour and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try VoIP Push notification Service.

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
     NSDictionary *payloadInfo = payload.dictionaryPayload;
     [self showLocalNotificationWithInfo: payloadInfo];
}

- (void) showLocalNotificationWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)infoDict{
     UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
     localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
     localNotification.alertBody = @"Your title message";

     localNotification.soundName = @"YourSoundFileName.mp3";
     localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
     localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
     localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
     localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

[Apple VoIP Push Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers. I found a reason of this behavior - the problem was with **badge** key in push notification body. This key had **0** value and thats why iOS marked new notifications as readed and they didn't add to Notification Center.